# C++/WinRT XAML controls bind to a property

Tags: winrt-xaml, c++-winrt

I am attempting to expand the Bookstore example by introducing an other ViewModel to have Sections within the book store. I my case I am calling it 'Library'. I am having difficulty in getting the books added to display in a second ListView. In MainPage in addition to the MainViewModel (which now displays the sections) I have added SubModelView to return the current Section. In my Xaml code I have constructed a second ListView with the code to display the books but it is not working. Can anybody advise what I am doing incorrectly. I have included a SubModelView in MainPage to access the current Section in which the books are being created and used this in the Xaml code.

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainPage.h"
#include "MainPage.g.cpp"


using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::UI::Popups;

namespace winrt::Library::implementation
{
    MainPage::MainPage()
    {
        m_mainViewModel = winrt::make<Library::implementation::LibraryViewModel>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Library::LibraryViewModel MainPage::MainViewModel()
    {
        return m_mainViewModel;
    }

    Library::Section MainPage::SubViewModel()
    {
        m_subViewModel = MainViewModel().Sectioncurrent();
        return m_subViewModel;
    }
}

void winrt::Library::implementation::MainPage::SectionButton_Click(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e)
{
    hstring sname{ Section_name().Text().c_str() };
    MainViewModel().Sectioncurrent(sname);
}


void winrt::Library::implementation::MainPage::TotleButton_Click(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e)
{
    if (MainViewModel().Sectioncurrent() == nullptr)
        return;
    hstring bname{ Title_name().Text().c_str() };
    MainViewModel().Sectioncurrent().Bookcurrent(bname);

    Library::Section subsec = SubViewModel();
    Library::Book bk = subsec.Bookcurrent();
    hstring tt = bk.Title();
}
```

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "LibraryViewModel.h"
#include "LibraryViewModel.g.cpp"

// Note: Remove this static_assert after copying these generated source files to your project.
// This assertion exists to avoid compiling these generated source files directly.
// static_assert(false, "Do not compile generated C++/WinRT source files directly");

namespace winrt::Library::implementation
{
    LibraryViewModel::LibraryViewModel()
    {
        m_section = winrt::single_threaded_observable_vector<Library::Section>();
    }

    Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Library::Section> LibraryViewModel::Sections()
    {
        return m_section;
    }

    void LibraryViewModel::Sectioncurrent(hstring const& sectionname)
    {
        m_sectionCurrent = winrt::make<Library::implementation::Section>(sectionname);
        Sections().Append(m_sectionCurrent);
    }

    Library::Section LibraryViewModel::Sectioncurrent()
    {
        return m_sectionCurrent;
    }

    winrt::event_token LibraryViewModel::PropertyChanged(Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler)
    {
        return m_propertyChanged.add(handler);
    }

    void LibraryViewModel::PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token) noexcept
    {
        m_propertyChanged.remove(token);
    }
}
```

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "Section.h"
#include "Section.g.cpp"

// Note: Remove this static_assert after copying these generated source files to your project.
// This assertion exists to avoid compiling these generated source files directly.
// static_assert(false, "Do not compile generated C++/WinRT source files directly");

namespace winrt::Library::implementation
{
   // Constructor
   Section::Section(hstring const& name) : m_sectionName{name}
   {
       m_section = winrt::single_threaded_observable_vector<Library::Book>();
   }

   Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Library::Book> Section::Books()
   {
       return m_section;
   }

   void Section::Bookcurrent(hstring const& name)
   {
       m_book = winrt::make<Library::implementation::Book>(name);
       Books().Append(m_book);
   }

   Library::Book Section::Bookcurrent()
   {
       return m_book;
   }

    hstring Section::SectionName()
    {
        return m_sectionName;
    }

    winrt::event_token Section::PropertyChanged(Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler)
    {
        return m_propertyChanged.add(handler);
    }

    void Section::PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token) noexcept
    {
        m_propertyChanged.remove(token);
    }
}
```

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="Library.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Library"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="Section_name" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="160,5,5,5" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 MinWidth="200"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Title_name" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,5,160,5" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                 MinWidth="200"/>
        <Button x:Name="SectionButton" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                Click="SectionButton_Click" Margin="160,5,5,5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left">Add Section</Button>
        <Button x:Name="TotleButton" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                Click="TotleButton_Click" Margin="5,5,160,5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right">Add Title</Button>
        <ListView x:Name="SectionList"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
                  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"
                  Margin="40,10,40,10"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind MainViewModel.Sections}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Section">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind SectionName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <ListView x:Name="TitleList"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"
                  Margin="40,10,40,10"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind SubViewModel.Books}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Book">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button x:Name="Process" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Click="Process_Click">PROCESS
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

```idl
import "LibraryViewModel.idl";

namespace Library
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MainPage : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page
    {
        MainPage();
        LibraryViewModel MainViewModel{ get; };
    }
}
```

```idl
import "SectionViewModel.idl";

namespace Library
{
    runtimeclass LibraryViewModel : Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        LibraryViewModel();
        Windows.Foundation.Collections.IObservableVector<SectionViewModel> Sections{ get; };
        void SectionViewModel(String sname);
        SectionViewModel SubViewModel{ get; };
    }
}
```

```idl
import "Book.idl";

namespace Library
{
    [bindable]
    runtimeclass SectionViewModel : Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        SectionViewModel(String name);
        String SectionName{ get; };
        Windows.Foundation.Collections.IObservableVector<Book> Books{ get; };
        void Book(String sname);
        Book BookCurrent{ get; };
    }
}
```

```idl
namespace Library
{
    [bindable]
    runtimeclass Book : Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Book(String title);
        String Title{ get; };
    }
}
```

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "MainPage.g.h"
#include "LibraryViewModel.h"

namespace winrt::Library::implementation
{
    struct MainPage : MainPageT<MainPage>
    {
        MainPage();
        Library::LibraryViewModel MainViewModel();
        
        void SectionButton_Click(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, 
            winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e);
        void TitleButton_Click(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, 
            winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e);
        void Process_Click(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, 
            winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e);
    private:
        Library::LibraryViewModel m_mainViewModel{ nullptr };
        Library::SectionViewModel m_sectionCurrent{ nullptr };
        winrt::event<Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler> m_propertyChanged;
       
    };
}

namespace winrt::Library::factory_implementation
{
    struct MainPage : MainPageT<MainPage, implementation::MainPage>
    {
    };
}
```

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "LibraryViewModel.g.h"
#include "SectionViewModel.h"

// Note: Remove this static_assert after copying these generated source files to your project.
// This assertion exists to avoid compiling these generated source files directly.
// static_assert(false, "Do not compile generated C++/WinRT source files directly");

namespace winrt::Library::implementation
{
    struct LibraryViewModel : LibraryViewModelT<LibraryViewModel>
    {
        LibraryViewModel();
        
        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Library::SectionViewModel> Sections();
        void SectionViewModel(hstring const& sname);
        Library::SectionViewModel SubViewModel();

        winrt::event_token PropertyChanged(Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler);
        void PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token) noexcept;
    private:
        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Library::SectionViewModel> m_section{ nullptr };
        Library::SectionViewModel m_sectionCurrent{ nullptr };
        winrt::event<Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler> m_propertyChanged;
    };
}
namespace winrt::Library::factory_implementation
{
    struct LibraryViewModel : LibraryViewModelT<LibraryViewModel, implementation::LibraryViewModel>
    {
    };
}
```

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "SectionViewModel.g.h"
#include "Book.h"

// Note: Remove this static_assert after copying these generated source files to your project.
// This assertion exists to avoid compiling these generated source files directly.
// static_assert(false, "Do not compile generated C++/WinRT source files directly");

namespace winrt::Library::implementation
{
    struct SectionViewModel : SectionViewModelT<SectionViewModel>
    {
        SectionViewModel() = delete;
        SectionViewModel(hstring const& name);
        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Library::Book> Books();
        hstring SectionName();
        void Book(hstring const& bname);
        Library::Book BookCurrent();
       
        winrt::event_token PropertyChanged(Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler);
        void PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token) noexcept;
    private:
        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Library::Book> m_books{ nullptr };
        hstring m_sectionName;
        Library::Book m_bookCurrent{ nullptr };
        winrt::event<Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler> m_propertyChanged;
    };
}
namespace winrt::Library::factory_implementation
{
    struct SectionViewModel : SectionViewModelT<SectionViewModel, implementation::SectionViewModel>
    {
    };
}
```

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Book.g.h"

// Note: Remove this static_assert after copying these generated source files to your project.
// This assertion exists to avoid compiling these generated source files directly.
// static_assert(false, "Do not compile generated C++/WinRT source files directly");

namespace winrt::Library::implementation
{
    struct Book : BookT<Book>
    {
        Book() = delete;
        Book(hstring const& title);
       // void Title(hstring const& value);
        hstring Title();
        winrt::event_token PropertyChanged(Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler);
        void PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token) noexcept;
    private:
        hstring m_title;
        winrt::event<Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler> m_propertyChanged;
    };
}
namespace winrt::Library::factory_implementation
{
    struct Book : BookT<Book, implementation::Book>
    {
    };
}
```

Comment: *"it is not working"* is not a problem statement. Please read [ask].

Comment: Thank you for responding. What I meant is that the Section names are displaying correctly in the ListView named "SectionList" but the Book titles are not displaying in the ListView named "TitleList". I hope this clarifies the problem.

Comment: Could you provide us the idl files of Section class and LibraryViewModel class?

Comment: Hi I attach the idl files as requested. As I have been changing the code to try to find a solution I also attach the corresponding .h and xaml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description and code, I assume that you want to add a layer called Section to your Library app. Input a Section name and add multiple books into the added Section with TextBox controls and Button controls. If you have any concerns about the following code, please feel free to contact us.

Here is a sample code for you:

Book.idl

```
namespace Library
{
    runtimeclass Book : Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Book(String title);
        String Title;
    }
}
```

Book.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Book.g.h"

// Note: Remove this static_assert after copying these generated source files to your project.
// This assertion exists to avoid compiling these generated source files directly.

namespace winrt::Library::implementation
{
    struct Book : BookT<Book>
    {
        Book() = default;

        Book(hstring const& title);
        hstring Title();
        void Title(hstring const& value);
        winrt::event_token PropertyChanged(Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler);
        void PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token) noexcept;
    private:
        winrt::hstring m_title;
        winrt::event<Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler> m_propertyChanged;
    };
}
namespace winrt::Library::factory_implementation
{
    struct Book : BookT<Book, implementation::Book>
    {
    };
}
```

Book.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Book.h"
#include "Book.g.cpp"

// Note: Remove this static_assert after copying these generated source files to your project.
// This assertion exists to avoid compiling these generated source files directly.

namespace winrt::Library::implementation
{
    Book::Book(hstring const& title):m_title{title}
    {
    }
    hstring Book::Title()
    {
        return m_title;
    }
    void Book::Title(hstring const& value)
    {
        if (m_title != value)
        {
            m_title = value;
            m_propertyChanged(*this, Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs{ L"Title" });
        }
    }
    winrt::event_token Book::PropertyChanged(Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler)
    {
        return m_propertyChanged.add(handler);
    }
    void Book::PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token) noexcept
    {
        m_propertyChanged.remove(token);
    }
}
```

Section.idl

```
import "Book.idl";

namespace Library
{
    runtimeclass Section: Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Section();
String SectionName{ get; set; };
void BookCurrent(String name);
Book BookCurrent();
Windows.Foundation.Collections.IObservableVector<Book> Books{ get; set; };
    }
}
```

Section.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Section.g.h"
#include "Book.h"

// Note: Remove this static_assert after copying these generated source files to your project.
// This assertion exists to avoid compiling these generated source files directly.

namespace winrt::Library::implementation
{
    struct Section : SectionT<Section>
    {
        Section() {
            m_books = winrt::single_threaded_observable_vector<Library::Book>();
        }

        hstring SectionName();
        void SectionName(hstring const& value);
        void BookCurrent(hstring const& name);
        Library::Book BookCurrent();
        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Library::Book> Books();
        void Books(Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Library::Book> const& value);
        winrt::event_token PropertyChanged(Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler);
        void PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token) noexcept;

    private:
        hstring m_sectionName;
        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Library::Book> m_books{ nullptr };
        Library::Book m_book{ nullptr };
        winrt::event<Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler> m_propertyChanged;

    };
}
namespace winrt::Library::factory_implementation
{
    struct Section : SectionT<Section, implementation::Section>
    {
    };
}
```

Section.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Section.h"
#include "Section.g.cpp"

// Note: Remove this static_assert after copying these generated source files to your project.
// This assertion exists to avoid compiling these generated source files directly.

namespace winrt::Library::implementation
{
    hstring Section::SectionName()
    {
        return m_sectionName;
    }
    void Section::SectionName(hstring const& value)
    {
        if (m_sectionName != value)
        {
            m_sectionName = value;
            m_propertyChanged(*this, Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs{ L"SectionName" });
        }
    }
    void Section::BookCurrent(hstring const& name)
    {
        m_book = Library::Book{ name };
        m_books.Append(m_book);
        m_propertyChanged(*this, Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs{ L"Book" });

    }
    Library::Book Section::BookCurrent()
    {
        return m_book;
    }
    Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Library::Book> Section::Books()
    {
        return m_books;
    }
    void Section::Books(Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Library::Book> const& value)
    {
        if (m_books != value)
        {
            m_books = value;
            m_propertyChanged(*this, Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs{ L"Books" });

        }
    }
    winrt::event_token Section::PropertyChanged(Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler)
    {
        return m_propertyChanged.add(handler);
    }
    void Section::PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token) noexcept
    {
        m_propertyChanged.remove(token);
    }
}
```

LibraryViewModel.idl

```
import "Section.idl";

namespace Library
{
    runtimeclass LibraryViewModel: Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        LibraryViewModel();
Section SectionViewModel();
void SectionViewModel(String name);
        Windows.Foundation.Collections.IObservableVector<Section> Sections{ get; };
        Section SectionCurrent{ get; set; };
    }
}
```

LibraryViewModel.h

```
#pragma once
#include "LibraryViewModel.g.h"
#include "Section.h"

// Note: Remove this static_assert after copying these generated source files to your project.
// This assertion exists to avoid compiling these generated source files directly.

namespace winrt::Library::implementation
{
    struct LibraryViewModel : LibraryViewModelT<LibraryViewModel>
    {
        LibraryViewModel() {
            m_sections = winrt::single_threaded_observable_vector<Library::Section>();
        }

        Library::Section SectionViewModel();
        void SectionViewModel(hstring const& name);
        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Library::Section> Sections();
        Library::Section SectionCurrent();
        void SectionCurrent(Library::Section const& value);

        winrt::event_token PropertyChanged(Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler);
        void PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token) noexcept;

    private:
        Library::Section m_section{ nullptr };
        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Library::Section> m_sections{ nullptr };
        Library::Section m_sectionCurrent{ nullptr };
        winrt::event<Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler> m_propertyChanged;

    };
}
namespace winrt::Library::factory_implementation
{
    struct LibraryViewModel : LibraryViewModelT<LibraryViewModel, implementation::LibraryViewModel>
    {
    };
}
```

LibraryViewModel.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "LibraryViewModel.h"
#include "LibraryViewModel.g.cpp"

// Note: Remove this static_assert after copying these generated source files to your project.
// This assertion exists to avoid compiling these generated source files directly.

namespace winrt::Library::implementation
{
    Library::Section LibraryViewModel::SectionViewModel()
    {
        return m_section;
    }
    void LibraryViewModel::SectionViewModel(hstring const& name)
    {
        m_section = Library::Section();
        m_section.SectionName(name);
        m_sections.Append(m_section);
    }
    Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Library::Section> LibraryViewModel::Sections()
    {
        return m_sections;
    }
    Library::Section LibraryViewModel::SectionCurrent()
    {
        //int t = m_sectionCurrent.Books().Size();
        return m_sectionCurrent;
    }
    void LibraryViewModel::SectionCurrent(Library::Section const& value)
    {
        if (m_sectionCurrent != value)
        {
            m_sectionCurrent = value;
            m_propertyChanged(*this, Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs{ L"SubViewModel" });

            m_sections.Append(m_sectionCurrent);
        }
    }
    winrt::event_token LibraryViewModel::PropertyChanged(Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler)
    {
        return m_propertyChanged.add(handler);
    }
    void LibraryViewModel::PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token) noexcept
    {
        m_propertyChanged.remove(token);
    }

}
```

MainPage.idl

```
import "BookstoreViewModel.idl";
import "Section.idl";
import "Book.idl";
import "LibraryViewModel.idl";

namespace Library
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MainPage : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page
    {
        MainPage();

    BookstoreViewModel MainViewModel{ get; };
    LibraryViewModel MyViewModel{ get; };
    Section SubViewModel{ get;};
    Windows.Foundation.Collections.IObservableVector<Book> Books{ get; };

    }
}
```

MainPage.h

```
#pragma once

#include "MainPage.g.h"
#include "BookstoreViewModel.h"
#include "Section.h"
#include "LibraryViewModel.h"

namespace winrt::Library::implementation
{
    struct MainPage : MainPageT<MainPage>
    {
        MainPage();
        Library::BookstoreViewModel MainViewModel();

        void Process_Click(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& args);
        Library::Section SubViewModel();
        //void CurrentSection(Library::Section const& value);
        Library::LibraryViewModel MyViewModel();
        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Library::Book> Books();
    private:
        Library::BookstoreViewModel m_mainViewModel{ nullptr };
        Library::Section m_subViewModel{ nullptr };
        Library::LibraryViewModel m_myViewModel{ nullptr };
        
    public:
        void ListView_SelectionChanged(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::SelectionChangedEventArgs const& e);
        void SectionButton_Click(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e);
        void TotleButton_Click(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e);
        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Library::Book> m_books{ nullptr };

    };
}

namespace winrt::Library::factory_implementation
{
    struct MainPage : MainPageT<MainPage, implementation::MainPage>
    {
    };
}
```

MainPage.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainPage.h"
#include "MainPage.g.cpp"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;

namespace winrt::Library::implementation
{
    MainPage::MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_mainViewModel = winrt::make<Library::implementation::BookstoreViewModel>();
        m_myViewModel = winrt::make<Library::implementation::LibraryViewModel>();

        m_subViewModel = winrt::make<Library::implementation::Section>();
        m_subViewModel.SectionName(L"sample");
        m_myViewModel.Sections().Append(m_subViewModel);

        m_books = winrt::single_threaded_observable_vector<Library::Book>();
    }

    void MainPage::Process_Click(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
    {

    }
    Library::BookstoreViewModel MainPage::MainViewModel()
    {
        return m_mainViewModel;
    }
    Library::Section MainPage::SubViewModel()
    {
        m_subViewModel = m_myViewModel.SectionCurrent();
        return m_subViewModel;
    }
    Library::LibraryViewModel MainPage::MyViewModel()
    {
        return m_myViewModel;
    }
    Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Library::Book> MainPage::Books()
    {
        return m_books;

    }
}


void winrt::Library::implementation::MainPage::ListView_SelectionChanged(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::SelectionChangedEventArgs const& e)
{
}


void winrt::Library::implementation::MainPage::SectionButton_Click(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e)
{
    hstring sname{ Section_name().Text().c_str() };
    auto section{ Library::Section() };
    section.SectionName(sname);
    m_books.Clear();
    m_myViewModel.SectionCurrent(section);
}


void winrt::Library::implementation::MainPage::TotleButton_Click(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e)
{
    if (m_myViewModel.SectionCurrent() == nullptr)
        return;
    hstring bname{ Title_name().Text().c_str() };
    m_books.Append(Library::Book(bname));
    m_myViewModel.SectionCurrent().Books(m_books);
    auto t = m_myViewModel.SectionCurrent().Books();

    auto t1 = t.Size();
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="Library.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Library"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="Section_name" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="160,5,5,5" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 MinWidth="200"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Title_name" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,5,160,5" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                 MinWidth="200"/>
        <Button x:Name="SectionButton" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                Click="SectionButton_Click" Margin="160,5,5,5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left">Add Section</Button>
        <Button x:Name="TotleButton" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                Click="TotleButton_Click" Margin="5,5,160,5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right">Add Title</Button>

        <ListView x:Name="SectionList"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
                  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"
                  Margin="40,10,40,10"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyViewModel.Sections}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Section">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind SectionName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        
        <ListView x:Name="TitleList"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"
                  Margin="40,10,40,10"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind Books,Mode=OneWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Book">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button x:Name="Process" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Click="Process_Click">PROCESS
        </Button>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Update:**

Please do some changes in above code:

Section.cpp

```
void Section::Books(Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Library::Book> const& value)
{
    if (m_books != value)
    {
        m_books = value;
        m_propertyChanged(*this, Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs{ L"Books" });

    }
    m_books = value;
}
```

LibraryViewModel.cpp

```
void LibraryViewModel::SectionCurrent(Library::Section const& value)
{
    if (m_sectionCurrent != value)
    {
        m_sectionCurrent = value;
        m_propertyChanged(*this, Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs{ L"SubViewModel" });

        bool flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_sections.Size(); i++)
        {
            if (m_sections.GetAt(i).SectionName() == value.SectionName())
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == false)
        {
            m_sections.Append(m_sectionCurrent);
        }
    }
}
```

Add the SelectionChanged of SectionList in MainPage.xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="SectionList"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
          BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"
          Margin="40,10,40,10"
          SelectionChanged="SectionList_SelectionChanged"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyViewModel.Sections}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Section">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind SectionName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
void winrt::Library::implementation::MainPage::SectionButton_Click(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e)
{
    hstring sname{ Section_name().Text().c_str() };
    auto section{ Library::Section() };
    section.SectionName(sname);

    m_books.Clear();

    m_myViewModel.SectionCurrent(section);
    SectionList().SelectedValue(section);
}

void winrt::Library::implementation::MainPage::TotleButton_Click(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e)
{
    if (m_myViewModel.SectionCurrent() == nullptr)
        return;
    hstring bname{ Title_name().Text().c_str() };
    m_books.Append(Library::Book(bname));
    int size = m_books.Size();
    m_myViewModel.SectionCurrent().Books().Append(Library::Book(bname));  //

}


void winrt::Library::implementation::MainPage::SectionList_SelectionChanged(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::SelectionChangedEventArgs const& e)
{
    auto selectedItem = SectionList().SelectedValue().try_as<Library::Section>();
    m_myViewModel.SectionCurrent(selectedItem);

    if (selectedItem != nullptr)
    {
        auto t1 = selectedItem.SectionName();
        m_books.Clear();
        auto size = selectedItem.Books().Size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            m_books.Append(selectedItem.Books().GetAt(i));
        }
        size = m_books.Size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your very comprehensive response. Your assumptions regarding my requirements are absolutely correct. I will review your solution fully and respond as soon as possible. In the meantime can you confirm if you intended to import the BookstoreViewModel.idl into the MainPage.idl and if so could you provide a copy of that idl file please.

Comment: There is no need to import BookstoreViewModel.idl to MainPage.idl in your scenario, you could delete this statement. If you need the BookstoreViewModel, you could get the code in official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/binding-collection#add-a-bookskus-collection-to-bookstoreviewmodel).

Comment: Thank you, I have eliminated the references to Bookstore and now have your proposed solution working. When a Section name is inserted and the Add Section Button is clicked the section name appears in the SectionList ListView. Similarly when a Book title is inserted and the Add Title button is clicked the book title now appears in the TitleList ListView. To be fair this is what I requested in my submission.

Comment: I have eliminated the references to Bookstore and now have your proposed solution working. When a Section name is inserted and the Add Section Button is clicked the section name appears in the SectionList ListView. To be fair this is what I requested in my submission..You have achieved this by creating a book vector in MainPage which is linked to the ListView in Xaml. However, the same vector of books is reused for each new Section created. Unfortunately, this leaves the problem that the books added to previously created Sections are no longer accessible. Have you any suggestions please.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to have the data source in Xaml dynamically link to the vector of books relating to the currently selected section? If this is possible it would resolve the problem. Many Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to bind a data source in Xaml dynamically to the vector of books relating to the currently selected section.

Comment: I have updated the answer, you could check if it could meet you requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have implemented the changes and everything now works as required. The SectionList_SelectionChanged event handler appears to be the principal missing ingredient in the solution. Many thanks again for your help.

Comment: If your problem is resolved, it is better if you could mark the answer so that poeple with the same problems could find a solution quickly.